# Keyboard hiding text field from WebView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, webview

Im using android `WebView`, below is the XML layout:

```
<ScrollView 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"     
     android:layout_height="match_parent"> 

    <WebView android:id="@+id/medical_webview" 
             android:layout_width="match_parent"  
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:focusable="true" 
             android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"> 
     </WebView> 
</ScrollView>
```

From `WebView`, textfield is in bottom of the page. Once we focus on the textfield UI is not scrolling up automatically and hiding the textfield.

More info, Im using `Fragment` and already tried with `adjustResize|adjustPan` .

Comment: please update your xml layout

Comment: where you have defined adjustresize|adjustpan?

Comment: <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/medical_webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        </WebView>
    </ScrollView>

Comment: @Anjali yea tried

Comment: I defined adjustresize in Manifest file of the base activity

Comment: is Scrollview is required in your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `Scrollview` and added:
`getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);`

Now it's working

Answer (score 0):

You have to define  adjustresize|adjustpan in your fragment class and not in your manifest:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE

After removing the scrollview and setting the layout params its working :)

Happy Coding!!!!

Comment: Still keyboard hiding the text field from webview

Comment: have you define fillViewPort to true in your scrollview

Comment: try to remove your scrollview and show only webview in your content